# Getting rails3-jquery-autocomplete to show the number of instances of posts with a certain tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Post* and *Tag* model with a many-to-many association:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post  
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I'm using rails3-jquery-autocomplete:

**posts_controller.rb:**

autocomplete :tag, :name

**routes.rb:**

```
  resources :posts do
    get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

**_form.html.erb:**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_names %><br />  
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_names, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
  </div>
```

I works fine but I would like the auto-complete drop-down to show the number of posts with a certain tag. Like this:

```
---------------------
| dr                |
---------------------
|drinks (23)        |
|drugs (4)       |
|                   |
---------------------
```

(Pretty much like StackOverflow)

I would appreciate any insight or example code.